# Best approach for Utility Class

Tags: java, spring

in my project I need a Set of all the holidays within an year.
My first approach was to use a static class with a method like this:

```
        Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
        giorniFestivi = new HashSet<GregorianCalendar>();

        GregorianCalendar newYearDay = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        GregorianCalendar epiphany = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.JANUARY, 6);
        GregorianCalendar easterMonday = CommonUtils.findEasterDay(now.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
        GregorianCalendar liberationDay = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.APRIL, 25);
        GregorianCalendar workerDay = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.MAY, 1);
        GregorianCalendar republicDay = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.JUNE, 2);
        GregorianCalendar ferragosto = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.AUGUST, 15);
        GregorianCalendar allSaints = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.NOVEMBER, 1);
        GregorianCalendar immaculate = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.DECEMBER, 8);
        GregorianCalendar christmasDay = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
        GregorianCalendar saintStephano = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.DECEMBER, 26);

        easterMonday.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);                                                                                                                                                    
        easterMonday.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR, 0);                                                                                                                                                    
        easterMonday.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);                                                                                                                                                  
        easterMonday.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 0);                                                                                                                                                  
        easterMonday.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

But i would avoid the creation of all these objects every time I call this method. So I've integrated my code with a "Singleton approach", returnin giorniFestivi directly if it is not null (it's a static attribute within my class).

Is this approach ok or it could be improved (I was also thinking about making this class a Spring Bean and getting it from context whenever i need it) ?

Ty in advance

Comment: Sorry, but this is a pretty broad question; and the only reasonable answer is: it depends. We don't know how your code is structured, we don't know how you solved similar problems in the past; so we are in no position to tell you what could be considered the "best" solution for your component. Anyway, in a certain way these "dates" represent constants; so it would be perfectly fair simple declare them as such.

Comment: The best approach would be to use an enum